# Python: Plotly Candlestick Chart with Scatter

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

**To recreate yourself:**
[CANDLESTICK CSV](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pattty847/Trading-Bot/main/Latest%20Bot/btcusdt-candles.csv) |
[ORDERS CSV](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pattty847/Trading-Bot/main/Latest%20Bot/btcusdt-orders.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def plot_ohlcv_plotly(df, orders):
        df.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms')
        fig = go.Figure(
            data=[go.Candlestick(
                    x=df['Date'],
                    open=df['Open'],
                    high=df['High'],
                    low=df['Low'],
                    close=df['Close'])])

        date = pd.to_datetime(orders['timestamp'], unit='ms')

        size = orders['size'] * 0.5

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=date, y=orders['price'], mode="markers", marker = dict(
                # color = orders['color'], <-- where color is set
                size=size
            )
        ))

        fig.show()


df = pd.read_csv('btcusdt-orders.csv')
candles = pd.read_csv('btcusdt-candles.csv')

grouped_multiple = df.groupby(['timestamp']).agg({'size': ['sum'], 'price': ['mean'], 'side':['first']})
grouped_multiple.columns = ['size', 'price', 'side']
orders = grouped_multiple.reset_index()

orders = orders.loc[orders['size'] > 20]

# pepe.plot_orders(grouped_multiple)
plot_ohlcv_plotly(candles, orders)
```

I have a simple question I can't seem to come up with a solution for.

What I want to do is plot a scatter chart on top of the candlestick chart which shows large orders that took place during the timeframe. **I got that to work so far.**

**Question:** *How can I change the color of the circle to match the side the order was placed on? So, 'buy' would set that circle to 'green' and 'red' for 'sell'.*

What I tried so far is python ternary assignment but the Series truth value cannot be assessed:

```
color = 'green' if orders['color'] == 'buy' else 'red'
```

The error told me to try adding .all(), .any(), .item(), .bool() to find out the truth value but .any() and .all() are the only ones without errors but it does not work for each row and each circle plotted.

I also tried creating a new column for color based on the values of the "side" column. But that did not work either.

**Here is my function for plotting the plotly chart:**

```
def plot_ohlcv_plotly(self, df, orders):
    df.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms')
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[go.Candlestick(
                x=df['Date'],
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'])])

    date = pd.to_datetime(orders['timestamp'], unit='ms')

    size = orders['size'] * 0.5

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=date, y=orders['price'], mode="markers", marker = dict(
            # color = orders['color'],
            size=size
        )
    ))

    fig.show()
```

**The orders csv file does contain rows where there are sells. So, the data does contain both buys and sells.**

```
timestamp,size,price,side

1664567708302,20.55188,19560.0,buy

1664568424915,29.02367,19450.0,buy

1664568480558,29.38344,19489.29,buy

1664569334535,30.37156,19490.0,sell

1664572312440,26.37094,19370.0,buy

1664572667156,25.87512,19350.0,sell

1664572746101,20.66364,19300.1,sell

1664572746103,53.43113,19300.0,sell

1664575734563,44.57541,19250.0,sell

1664575734563,31.07015,19250.0,buy

1664575734594,31.94762,19250.0,buy

1664577201634,22.63745,19345.01,sell

1664579865001,29.92649,19390.18,sell

1664581629722,22.07112,19427.09,sell
```

[image: As you can see the circles always show up as sells.]

Comment: Your df contains 6 columns, while the CSV file contains 4 columns?

Comment: That is correct. The candlestick chart is plotted with the df dataframe and the scatter with the orders dataframe. There are two CSV files, one for the candles(6 columns) and one for the orders (4 columns)

Comment: You should add the dataframe to the question to help others reproduce your work to help you.

Comment: @Hamzah Good idea, thank you for the advice. I added the whole project to the top of the post.

Comment: There are a lot of files, I think it would be a good idea to add the necessary code to your question to at least plot the graph shown above.

Comment: @Hamzah True, just updated sorry for back and forth I haven't made posts other than one before.

Comment: The problem is still with number of columns of df inside the function. The df contains only 4 columns and you try to assign 6 columns to it.

Comment: @Hamzah I'm not sure it's that because plotly uses add_trace which just adds another chart to the figure and works fine. It's the colors of the circles I want to change to be green or red depending upon the "side" column.
I don't get any dataframe errors with column issues.

Comment: I did not get the same plot as yours, it is a weird graph. Are you sure that the code above with the data will generate the same plot above?

Comment: @Hamzah If you could copy and paste the code from the top again, I have updated it to remove the self parameter on the function and removed the pepe object.
I'm feel like you caught that tho, however It does produce the same chart for me.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a list of determined colors must be set. So I have a list of your criteria in comprehension at the color designation.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def plot_ohlcv_plotly(df, orders):
    df.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms')
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[go.Candlestick(
            x=df['Date'],
            open=df['Open'],
            high=df['High'],
            low=df['Low'],
            close=df['Close'],
            name='Chandlestick')
             ]
    )

    date = pd.to_datetime(orders['timestamp'], unit='ms')

    size = orders['size'] * 0.5

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=date,
        y=orders['price'],
        mode="markers",
        name='side',
        marker = dict(
            color = ['green' if s == 'buy' else 'red' for s in orders['side']],
            size=size,
        )
    ))
    fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=600, xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)))
    fig.show()

plot_ohlcv_plotly(df, orders)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. I see the difference in the way I was doing it and the list comprehension. I would upvote but I need more reputation.